# concatenating methods of lambdas and calling the functional interface's method only one time

Tags: java

I am studying JAVA functional interfaces and lambdas. I haven't studied other languages like Python, so I (still) don't get analogies to them (as indicated in other parts of the web).

I came across a similiar code:

```
interface Function<T,R> {
    // T der Argumenttyp
// R der Ergebnistyp
    R apply (T arg);
    default <V> Function<T,V> andThen (
            Function<? super R, ? extends V> after) {
        return (T x) -> after.apply(apply(x));
    }
}

class S implements Function<String,String> {
    public String apply(String t) {return t+1;}
}
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        S f = new S();

        Function<String,String> g = f.andThen(f);

        System.out.println(g.andThen(g).apply("Hello"));    //<--- The given code.
        //System.out.println(g.apply(g.apply("Hello")));    //<--- What I would have done.
    }
}
```

The commented line is what I would have used instead of the last line. Both run and deliver the same result, namely "Hello1111".

Question: Why does also the other option work?

The reason I am happy with my piece of code is that I am calling 'apply' 2 times: I have a Function-interface object 'g', I call apply on it and I get the String: "Hello11". I then treat this result as a parameter for a new 'apply' call and do the same. Key point: the 'andThen' method returns me an interface object on which I can call 'apply'.

The part of the given code which I do not understand is the following:

```
g = f.andThen(f);
g.andThen(g).apply("Hello")
```

I agree that g in the first line is a Function-interface object on which I can call 'apply'.
And I also agree that 'g.andThen(g)' is some Function-interface object on which I can call 'apply'. And so far my analysis has been purely formal. I don't see what *exactly* happens in the second line.

ADDENDUM:
In other words I am asking not what happens in a std case like: `f.andThen(f).apply("Hello")`

but in this:
`f.andThen(f.andThen(f)).apply("Hello")`

There is only 1 apply ‘call’, and 2 ‘andThen’. How are the 2 ‘andThen’’s lambda expressions put together in relation to the ‘apply’ call?

Comment: If I showed you `f.andThen(f).apply("Hello")`, would you understand what it means and be able to tell me what it returns?

Comment: and what if you have a method that only accepts one function? that is only called once (e.g. you need to pass it a function that squares a number and then converts it somehow to another Type - using functions/methods that are already defined)

Comment: @Sweeper f.andThen(f).apply("Hello") returns “Hello11”. So far so good. It still doesn’t answer my question: see Addendum.

Comment: I don't see the issue; what exactly are you asking for an explanation of? It seems you understand what `.andThen` does in the first case (which is no different to the second case), and you understand what the result is because you would prefer to write something else which has the same result.

Comment: ADDENDUM `andThen()` will create a (composed) *function*, when its `apply` is executed it will call `apply` of first function (`this` object of `andThen`) and use  the result in call to `apply` of second function (argument of `andThen`)

Comment: lets change last snippet to `f1.andThen(f2.andThen(f3).apply()`. The argument of `apply` will be used to call `f1.apply`; the result as argument to call `apply` of  `f2.andThen(f3)`, which will also be expanded to call of `f2.apply` and its result used as argument to `f3.apply` - At the end the sequence is `f1.apply`, `f2.apply` and `f3.apply`  (apply of composed functions not being showed)